# Fresh ground chorizo

Tags: baking, fresh, ground, chorizo

If I am using ground fresh chorizo in an oven baked dish with chicken, do I need to brown it on the stove top first?

Comment: What do you mean by ground chorizo? Chorizo is made of minced or ground meat, but one wouldn't normally "grind" the sausage itself. Also, is it Mexican-style or Spanish-style chorizo?

Comment: depends on the recipe, please share the recipe

Answer (score 1):

This is determined by the outcome you desire.  You can certainly safely cook fresh chorizo in the oven.  You just need to be sure it reaches at least 150 F (65.5C). Browning it on the stove first will at least partially cook it (if not fully cook it), but it could also add caramelized notes and texture that is desirable in your final product.   So, it really depends on your recipe.